# Problem passing data from repository to viewmodel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, viewmodel

I have the following viewmodel,

```
public class SiteAdminCreateViewModel
{
    public Customer Customer { get; private set; }
    public CustomerSite CustomerSite { get; private set; }
    public SelectList CustomerNames { get; private set; }

    public SiteAdminCreateViewModel(CustomerSite customerSite, Customer customer)
    {
        CustomerSite = customerSite;
        Customer = customer;
        CustomerNames = new SelectList(customer.CustomerName);
    }
}
```

And the following methods in my repository for returning a list of customers and a list of CustomerSites

```
 public IQueryable<CustomerSite> GetCustomerSites
    {
        get { return context.CustomerSites; }
    }
    public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers
    {
        get { return context.Customers; }
    }
```

When i instanitiate the viewmodel in my controller im wanting to return the list of customers to passs to the select list in the viewmodel.

```
 public ViewResult Create() 
    {
        CustomerSite customerSite = new CustomerSite();
        var customer = repository.GetCustomers.ToList();
        return View(new SiteAdminCreateViewModel(customerSite, customer));       
    }
```

But the return line throws the error

cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'CustomerOrders.Domain.Entities.Customer

I think this is because i have the customer variable defined in the Viewmodel of type Customer but im trying to pass a list of customers?

Can anyone offer any advice on where i am going wrong here?

Do i need to define both the Customer type and the CustomerNames select list type in the viewmodel, i defined the Customer Object only so i can use it to pass the Customers to the select list but im not sure if this is the best way to do this?

Any advice anyone can offer for a newbie, will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SiteAdminCreateViewModel` class' constructor is defined as follows:

```
public SiteAdminCreateViewModel(CustomerSite customerSite, Customer customer) {
   ...
}
```

Its second argument is of type `Customer`.

You're passing `var customer = repository.GetCustomers.ToList()` to it, whose type is `List<Customer>`.

---

> When i instanitiate the viewmodel in my controller im wanting to
>   return the list of customers to passs to the select list in the
>   viewmodel.

If I understand what you're saying correctly, you're just trying to pass the customers list to build a `SelectList`.

First of all, you seem to be passing a string to the `SelectList` constructor. This would not even compile (read [System.Web.Mvc.SelectList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.aspx)).

What you'd need to do is change `SiteAdminCreateViewModel`'s constructor like

```
public SiteAdminCreateViewModel(CustomerSite customerSite, IEnumerable<Customer> customers) {
   /* ... */
   CustomerNames = new SelectList(customers, "CustomerId", "CustomerName");
}
```

`CustomerId` and `CustomerName` being properties of the `Customer` class.

Comment: thanks for your advice ive changed the constructor, can you kindly offer any advice on how to ammnend the IQueryable method for returning the Customers from the repository, to fit with the ICollection as i get another conversion error stating unable to convert from IQueryable to ICollection, thanks again

Comment: @Liam, use `IEnumerable` instead?

Comment: tried that but i still get the conversion error unable to convert from IEnumerable to ICollection.

Answer (score 0):

it's simply because you are trying to pass IList into constructor of the  SiteAdminCreateViewModel

```
var customer = repository.GetCustomers.ToList();
        return View(new SiteAdminCreateViewModel(customerSite, customer));
```

using

```
var customer = repository.GetCustomers.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
            return View(new SiteAdminCreateViewModel(customerSite, customer));
```

would work, also you may need to check if the customer is null